# Is it possible to automate generating a @2x asset by nearest-neighbour scaling when editing a graphical asset @1x?

Tags: gimp, automation, scale, pixel-art, sprite

Say I have a PNG image file called image.png that I edit pixel by pixel that is 16 pixels wide by 16 pixels tall (16x16).

For my usage purposes, I need it to eventually be 3 times in size (i.e. 48 x 48) scaled using the nearest-neighbour scaling algorithm (all hard edges; no blurriness).

Currently, I do this manually and export two versions of the same asset, image.png (original) and image@3x.png (48 x 48), every time I make changes, which is somewhat of a hassle. Is there a way to automate my system to generate image@3x.png every time I save changes to image.png? (I am on a Mac).

I am using Gimp.

Comment: Yes, conceptually. But the real reason why I need the asset to physically be 3x in size is due to the requirements of the framework I am using these assets in.

More context: I'm designing a game in RPG maker MV which requires tiles to be 48x48. I am designing my graphics with a 16x16 aesthetic, so I just need to blow then up to 3x.

Comment: Yeh I just noticed this was tagged pixel-art, in which case this is obviously what you want to do :) (deleted my comment because it isn't really relevant)

Comment: What software are you using? Or are you asking for a recommendation of software that could do this?

Comment: I'm using GIMP. Would be preferable to not have to use another software. Wondering if I could simply include a script in the same folder that executes whenever I save changes to certain files.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`-magnify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#magnify) option in Imagemagick. I don't have a recent install of IM handy to test, but that sounds like what you are trying to do.

Comment: You might want to use something other than nearest-neighbor. See, for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_art_scaling_algorithms

Comment: Note that GIMP supports scripting, so you might be able to run a script on the image that saves it as step one, then does some {magic} and saves a second copy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The scripting one sounds like a possible solution if I decide to stick with GIMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized too late you wanted a workflow for GIMP but I wrote it for photoshop since you were using the notation to generate image assets.

Open your preferences with Ctrl + K or from the edit menu

Change the default image interpolation to Nearest Neighbor

Generate image assets should now use Nearest neighbor scaling. All that is left is to set up your layers to export automatically using generate image assets,(200% layername.png)

[image]

Version: Photoshop CC 2017

Comment: Thanks. I think I should be able to switch over to Photoshop.